# Getting total value from each field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I get the Total value of Yes, No, Other fields of each username?

I like to add Total field.

```
SELECT Username,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as No,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = '' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Other  
  //How to get total of Yes/No/Other
  FROM table 
WHERE source = 'CompanyName' ";
```

Also the highest Total goes at the top order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use 0 instead of `NULL`, add the missing `group by` and use `COUNT(*)` to get the total of each group and order the result:

```
SELECT Username,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as No,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other,  
  COUNT(*) as TOTAL
  FROM table 
WHERE source = 'CompanyName'
group by Username
order by TOTAL desc;
```

This assumes that `type` can only be 'Yes', 'No'  or ''.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. What about the total?

Comment: The `count(*)` makes sense, but won't return the same value if there are any `type = 'maybe'` values in there.

Comment: Also `order by COUNT(*) desc`, as otherwise the highest total will be last.

Comment: @Keith: Thanks for spotting the missing `desc`. About other types: Yes you are right and I actually already explain this in my answer.

Comment: If you really need to make sure of the types, something like `SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('Yes', 'No', '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` should work fine.

Comment: +1 for `This assumes that type can only be 'Yes', 'No' or ''.`

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub query to sum up your results and add a sort:

```
select yes, no, other, yes + no + other as Total
from (

    SELECT Username,
      SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes,
      SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as No,
      SUM(CASE WHEN type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other  
      FROM table 
    WHERE source = 'CompanyName'
)
order by (yes + no + other) desc
```

Comment: @Johan - I might have read this wrong, but doesn't he want to get an overall total and sort by it descending?

Comment: missed that one, got too zoomed in on the sum(1,1,1,null) thing.

Comment: BTW you can order by the alias, you don't have to repeat the expression in your order by clause. It will speed up things.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SUM(null), the SUM of (1,1,1,null) = null, not 3.

```
SELECT s.*, s.yes+s.no+s.other as all FROM (
  SELECT Username,
     SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes,
     SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as No,
     SUM(CASE WHEN type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other  
     FROM table 
   WHERE source = 'CompanyName'
   GROUP BY Username
) s
ORDER BY all DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. What about the total?

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, here you go.